# Test if graph is connected in Igraph on Python

Tags: python, networkx, igraph

In Python (I haven't check in R), Igraph tells me that a graph G is not connected using G.is_connected() while Networkx tells me it is connected using nx.is_connected(G).

Knowing my graph, I know networkx is right on that one.

Is there a known bug somewhere, or the two packages have different definitions of what a connected graph is?

In fact, I'd like to know if my graph is connected in the sense that there is a path from any vertice to any other vertices in the graph.

How to do this with igraph?

Here's my code:

```
from igraph import *
import networkx as nx

(read_a_graph_and_put_it_in_G)

G = G.to_undirected()               
print nx.is_connected(G)

adjG = nx.to_numpy_matrix(G.to_undirected())
G = Graph.Adjacency(adjG.tolist())
G.to_undirected()
print G.is_connected()
```

The first print gives TRUE, the seconde gives FALSE

Comment: To help diagnose your problem, you'll have to share with us a MWE (Minimal Working Example) - as it stands this isn't enough to go on.

Comment: I added my code, cheers!

Comment: so, there is a step in between, which might be where things are going wrong. you can write to a file (e.g. graphml) from both networkx and igraph - perhaps it's worth trying some different ways of transferring the graph, and/or dumping the output from both and comparing them.

Comment: Can you share your Graph with us so we can see where they differ? Have you tried different graphs and see if/when the two differ. One trick is to keep removing nodes/edges to see if networkx and igraph are still different.

Comment: Again, does this problem persist? If we can see the graph, we can help. Otherwise, it would be helpful to close the question.

Comment: What does `count_components()` return for `G`? I just ran in to something similar related to the strong or weak modes in `is_connected()`, but I second @AryaMcCarthy and @Ram Narasimhan that it would be helpful to se the actual graph.